# What rewards are considered higher quality?

Tags: payday-2

In Ghost tree, Lucky Charm gives you an increased chance of getting a higher quality item as a reward on payday card draw.

[image: Lucky Charm - Your chance of getting a higher quality item during a PAYDAY is increased.]

Which items are considered higher quality? Are different weapon parts also in quality order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lucky charm perk increases your chance of getting infamous items (Special masks, patterns, colours and materials).

By how much it increases your chance is not clear, as of yet. There are, however some speculations about it (see links).

[How useful is lucky charm?](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115100604308/)

[about lucky charm skill](http://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/0/864976115271990617/)

Comment: What are these infamous items?

Comment: Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

apparently $12000 over and over is higher quality

Comment: Could you explain your answer a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

It increases your chance of getting an infamous item by 100% the first point you put into it and by 500% when you ace it